# If checkbox is checked then gridview particular column gets copied to another column

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

There are 4 columns in my gridview.

When the page loads, the 3rd column[text box] has some values. Now the user has to update the 4th column. Then it struck me: why not use a checkbox on the header of 4th column? If user thinks all the 3rd column values are correct, then check the checkbox and the something populates in 4th column each row as per 3rd column.

Now in the header template of 4th column a checkbox is there. If the user checks that checkbox. Then all the corresponding 3rd row values are updated in 4th column.

Here is the aspx page[3rd and 4th column(4th column is having checkbox in header) ]--

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approved Km By Ops">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtdistanceops" MaxLength="6" class="test"  
                     CssClass="textBox_for6tds" runat="server"
                     Text='<%#Bind("distanceByOps") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Approved Km By CTV" Visible="false">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbcopy" runat="server" Text="Approved Km By CTV"/>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtdistancectv" MaxLength="6" class="test" 
             CssClass="textBox_for6tds" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now I was trying like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
       $(function(){
       $('[id*=chkbcopy]').click(function(){
       var chkHeader = $(this);
               if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) 
               {

                     $("[id*='txtdistancectv']").val($("[id*='txtdistanceops']").val());                     
               }
               else
               {
                   $("[id*='txtdistancectv']").val('');
               }
            });
       });
        </script>
```

But it's copying the first row of gridview to all the text box.

Means if if in column 3 the values are

```
3 4 5 6 7 8 19 23
```

Column four values are fetched like

```
3 3 3 3 3 3 3  3
```

Comment: The jquery is wrong ...i am unable to solve that...When checkbox is checked....suppose if the 3rd column value are like 4,5.18,32...Then 4th column of gridview should also populate like 4,5,18,32....I am unable to do that(exactly jquery has to be written in such a way that it should iterate through each row of the 3rd column....and the same thing will be assigned in 4th column)

Comment: You can test it easier (and make it easier for others to help) if you capture a page of your html output and put it and your code in a JSFiddle.

Comment: .. and simplify the code to the absolute minimum that shows your problem.

Comment: help me otherwise how to iterate through each row of a gridview column using jquery